# Woocommerce Free shipping method

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like add new functionality on my site which requirement is given below.
I spent to much time in google but I didn't find any plugin.

Requirement:

**ON CHECKOUT Page, I want an option to choose "Bring to _____ event verses shipping." and then user don't have to pay shipping.**

Is there any plugin which fulfilled my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this plugin will help you.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-event-manager/